# How to block phishing email in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, spam-prevention

I keep getting some unwanted email from `info@displaymailbox.com` at least 20 emails/day. I tried to unsubscribe but no luck in that. I tried to all the way I can't block at all. Finally, I decided to move all mail to spam. Is there any way to stop this?

Comment: Don't unsubscribe spam that you never subscribed, Many spams mails are actually fake unsubscribe scam that trick you to help spammer to confirm your are active. Throw the mail into spam box, the heuristic filter should do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can report phishing directly to Google

[image]
[image]

apart of that you can:

- report spam
- label it as spam
- block it
- mute it

Answer (score 0):

Gmail allows you to block email addresses. Open the email in Gmail and click the down arrow on the right of the screen, there is an option to block "spammer" (where the spammer is the name of the sender). This will send all future mail from that address to spam.

Alternatively, if you don't even want to send the mail to spam, you could create a filter in the settings under 'Filters and Blocked Addresses' for mail from the spammers address and then in the filter select 'delete it'.